# facebook app counter new entry

Tags: facebook, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, count, uinavigationitem

Im new to facebook app development. But i manage to get facebook login on my site.
No i wish to show feedback of my site (new entrys) and pass it to app counter.
(span .count uiSideNavCount) on facebook. Im searching for any info about it but can't find anything about that topic. Any help, info, documents maybe a tutorial will be very appriciated.

http://gathernet.eu/lots/forum/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_rel_module=post&attach_id=17

Answer (score 1):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

This is what i was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

That link is bad:  [#10171] You do not have permission to view this attachment.

Do you absolutely need to use a third-party API, or can you use one of the free Facebook APIs?  If so, you can do a simple login here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/